# Highlight text on page if matching text exist in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highlight

I'm trying to highlight the text on the page if it matches the text in my array. The goal is to highlight the duplicates on the page.

```
var iterator = document.evaluate('xpathgoeshere', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  var arrayList = [];

  while (thisNode) {
    arrayList.push(thisNode.textContent); 
    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  }

  console.log(arrayList);

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    console.log(arrayList[i]);
  }   
} catch (e) {
  dump('Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e);
}

var arrayListDupes = arrayList.slice().sort();
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayListDupes.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arrayListDupes[i + 1] == arrayListDupes[i]) {
    //while (results) {
        results.style.outline = "5px dashed red"; // I am probably doing
        results = iterator.iterateNext(); // it completely incorrect
        results.push(arrayListDupes[i]);
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: As of now, it is completely unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My array (arrayList) returns titles "Title 1, Title 2, Title 3, Title 2" etc. If there is any duplicate my other array (results) returns "Title 2". I would like to highlight "Title 2" on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use you existing code with the below function.

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
```

Try calling like `findString (results[0])` , the text should highlight in the page.

`findString()` source and demo [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot kiranvj, I really like this function! :)

Comment: You are welcome, make sure you check browser support before using in prod.